# Read content from the xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

i want to read content form  xml file in the below format in c# . Please let me know

```
<Company>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName>FN</FirstName>
    <LastName>LN</LastName>
  </Employee>
 <Employee>
   <FirstName>FN1</FirstName>
   <LastName>SN1</LastName>
 </Employee>
</Company>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XML String to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object)

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading XML nodes as C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850289/reading-xml-nodes-as-c-sharp-objects)

Comment: There are many possibilities. Read it as text file and parse it line by line, write a parser based on objects, .... . SO is there to  help you with error in your code, not to do your work. Just type to google "c# .net XML parse"

Comment: I dont want to convert it to object as mentioned in the Drag and Drop link . i just want to show the content in the xml file to end users

Comment: So you just want to read a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> names = doc.Descendants("Employee")
                .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>((string)x.Element("FirstName"), (string)x.Element("LastName")))
                .ToList();


        }
    }
}
```